# How to Get the Value of Bootsramp btn-group Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi can you please help me to figure out how to get the value of selected btn-group in Bootsramp using jQuery?

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/QXvHz/) and this the code for `class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio":`

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this by  [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('.btn-group .btn').on("click",function(){

   alert($(this).text())
})
```

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 2):

Some jQuery like this will do the trick:

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-group .btn").on('click', function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });        
});​
```